# How can I get the emoji character count as 1 text length?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

When I add emojis in my app, some emojis also take the text length as 1 and some as 2. How can I get them all to be taken as 1 character?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7FP5.jpg

Comment: why have you included a screenshot that adds NOTHING to the question?

Comment: @JaromandaX what ? question at the top of the page

Comment: What is the point of the BIG image with large amount of white space? Please remove the image as it is absolutely pointless and adds NO information

Comment: It is UTF so you need to count the code points.